# How to add a row which as only 1 attribute in a table which has 2 attributes as a composite primary key?

Tags: sql, oracle

Example:-
I have a table called Person which has 2 columns person_id and skill. Primary key is (person_id, skill)

Person:-
Person_id  |    Skill

```
        1     | skill_a
        1     | skill_b
        2     | skill_a
```

So a person can have many skills. But how can I add a person who has no skill (as skil column doesn't take null values)

Comment: Rename the table to `Person_Skill` and have a separate table called `Person` for storing Persons?

Comment: Yes. That can be a solution. and a query like the one below can be me person with no skills.

select person_id from person
minus
select person_id from person_skill, person where person.person_id=person_skill.person_id


Unfortunately I have many such tables which I might have to break into 2 tables. And 1 of the 2 new tables will have just 1 attribute (Like person here has just 1 column - person_id).

Comment: Only one attribute? Will you not store anything else about Persons? Only their ID? Not their name or birthday or whatever other information your application needs (about persons)?

Comment: And the query would be simpler actually: `select person_id from person minus select person_id from person_skill ;`

Answer (score 0):

```
insert table person(person_id) values('3')
```

and set skill to null

if you set person_id,skill is primary key then you not set null.

because primary_key= **unique** + **not null**

Comment: skill is part of the primary key. It cannot take null values.

Comment: This just explains why the OP can't do what he wants. It doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There two constraint in sql

1. Primary key
2. Unique key

Both are used for avoid duplicate.  Unique key allow null values only once.  But primary key does not allow null values.

Better use UNIQUE constraint instead of a PRIMARY KEY constraint to achieve that.

Comment: This just explains why the OP can't do what he wants. It doesn't solve the problem.